# Add data table pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to add data table pagination:

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered"id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">
```

... continue

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific issue are you having with implementing table pagination?

Comment: Does this question refer to DataTables (the [jQuery library](https://datatables.net/))? If so, the correct tag to use is `datatables`, not `datatable`. You get pagination out-of-the-box with DataTables. You don't need to "add" anything. If this is _not_ a DataTables question, then please [edit] the question to clarify what you are using.

Comment: You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more information on how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can add pagination via new class added to your table-responsive as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable(); //your data table id
        $('.table-responsive').addClass('bs-select'); //add class
    });
```